# What is method to count number of pages from search results (Java)?

Tags: java

I have a list of searched results from DB, I also have pageSize & I want to count noOfPages

```
int pageSize=3;
int totalResults=...;
int noOfPages=methodX(totalResults/pageSize);
```

So, if `totalResults=9` then `noOfPages=3`, if `totalResults=100` then `noOfPages=34`even 100/3 =33.33
So basically it will round up no matter how much fraction, as long as there's a fraction then it will round up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Traditional" solution for JDK 1.0 :)

```
int totalResults = 10;
int pageSize = 3;
int result;

if (totalResults % pageSize == 0) {
    result = totalResults / pageSize;
} else {
    result = totalResults / pageSize + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way

```
result = (totalResults + pageSize - 1) / pageSize;
// 
// eg: totalResults=10,pageSize=3 => result = 4 = (10 + 3 - 1) / 3
// eg: totalResults=12,pageSize=3 => result = 4 = (12 + 3 - 1) / 3
```

or

```
result = totalResults / pageSize + totalResults % pageSize > 0 ? 1 : 0
```

or

```
result = (int) Math.ceil((float)totalResults/pageSize);
```